# How do I handle several submit forms with same handler? (google app engine-python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, forms

In `AdminPage` I've created several forms to edit the form fields in the database; all forms refer to the `action=/adminpage`

```
<form name="submit_form" action="/adminpage" method="post">
```

then I created a `def post(self):` to handle each form, for instance

```
def post(self):
   ....
   handle first form

def post(self):
    ...
    handle second form
```

and so on.

Obviously this is wrong because each `def post(self):` works on its own; only when I add the others they don't work.

I searched how to pass the name of the form to the script but could not find anything useful. What is your suggestion to handle each form without creating a separate handler for each? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what's wrong with having a separate handler for each form? If you do decide you want to go down this path, you have a couple options. You could either check the referrer URL to see what page the user came from and infer what was submitted. Another option is to place a hidden field in each form that specifies which form is being submitted.

Note that with either of these methods, a malicious user could easily game the system to make you think you're processing a different type of form. Up to you whether or not this is a concern. If you do want to use the same handler for several forms, just make sure not to mix in forms which perform privileged actions.

Comment: Please, please don't use the referer. And there's no more vulnerability in using a hidden field than there is in using different handler URLs.

Comment: I agree. I don't think it's a good idea, as I mentioned in my answer. I was suggesting possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a hidden input element in each form and then use value of that field to distinguish between different forms on the page. E.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="form_name" value="submit_form" style="display:none"></input>
```

And then you can use value of form_name in your post() to figure out which form is being submitted.

Comment: Instead of using `style="display:none"`, use `type="hidden"`.